# place angular 2 router components as sibling DOM elements

Tags: angular, angular2-router

I need to place router components as siblings not as nested views, how I can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: the image is unavailable

Comment: The Router places components as siblings to `<router-outlet>`. If this is not what you want, you can implement a custom `<router-outlet>` component.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer 
no, I  mean to place the <router-outlet> as 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
not as nested
<router-outlet>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </router-outlet>

Comment: You can use named outlets to be able to place more then one `<router-outlet>`, but that won't work with such simple URLs. I'd suggest you think of a different strategy. For example you can use a path like `{path: ':cmp1/:cmp2/:cmp3', component: Container }` and then in container evaluate the `route.params` and add the components to `Container` using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` yourself.